# How to center horizontally an absolute button in a div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to center an absolute button in a div (in the bottom), but it seems to not be working.. Here's what I'm doing for now:

```css
.mc-item {
  background: #F0F0F0;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.mc-item a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -19px;
  left: 50%;
}

.mc-item p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
  <div class="mc-item">
    <p>Changez votre adresse email ou votre mot de passe.</p>
    <a asp-controller="MyAccount" asp-action="Settings" class="btn btn-primary">Paramètres</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This gives the following result:

[image]

What I want is the button centered in the middle. Does the `left: 50%` takes in consideration the whole `.col div`? I tried wrap the `button` in a `div` and `div`'s width becomes 380 which is the same as the `.col div` (not the `div` with the `<p>`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to `transform: translateX(-50%);` your button

Comment: Instead of what? Should I remove the `left: 50%` ? I replaced it and it goes out of the div (in the left).

Comment: Nope, just add it to your button

Comment: It works perfectly, can you explain how did this fix the issue?

Comment: The target of the `left` attribute is the left of the button, a translate takes the width of your button and it translate your button -50% of it width to the right, so 50% of the button width to the left

Answer (score 1):

`Left:50%` will make the element, start from center position of container. So the element is still not in center but `Transform: translate(-50%,0)` will move the element to the left of 50% of its width. So now the center of element meets the horizontal center of its container.

```css
.mc-item {

  background: #F0F0F0;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.mc-item a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -19px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,0)
}

.mc-item p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
  <div class="mc-item">
    <p>Changez votre adresse email ou votre mot de passe.</p>
    <a asp-controller="MyAccount" asp-action="Settings" class="btn btn-primary">Paramètres</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.mc-item {
    background: #F0F0F0;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    height: 140px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.mc-item a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -19px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.mc-item p {
    text-align: center;
}
```